# How to retrieve Apache Solr's current search filters?

Tags: 7, search

I'm using [Apache Solr Search](https://www.drupal.org/project/apachesolr), [Search API](https://www.drupal.org/project/search_api) and [Facet API](https://www.drupal.org/project/facetapi).

Is there a way to retrieve the current search filters being used when using Apache Solr on Drupal?

For example: I have a website using facets which reference a taxonomy called colours.  In this facet, there's a list of colours - if I select Green, this generates an Apache Solr search - using green as the filter.

`www.example-website.com/?f[0]=field_colour%3A2712.......etc`

When the Solr search is created - I guess, I could grab the term id `2712` from the URL using GET - but there must be a cleaner way.

Any ideas?

Comment: Which SOLR module are you using (apache_solr or search_api_solr)?

Comment: I'm using apachesolr, search_api and facet_api - cheers

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you're writing a module to do this?

If so, if you're implementing something like the `apachesolr_query_alter(&$query)` hook or something like that, which gives you access to the search query, you can use

```
function [getFilters][1]($name = NULL)
```

Note that the `name` parameter is optional: Returns all filters matching `$name`, if set; otherwise, **returns all filters**.

Answer (score 0):

I did it using [FacetApiAdapter](http://drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/contributions!apachesolr!plugins!facetapi!adapter.inc/class/ApacheSolrFacetapiAdapter/7) (see [facetapi_adapter_load](http://drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/contributions!facetapi!facetapi.module/function/facetapi_adapter_load/7)):

```
// Get an instance of FacetApiAdapter
$searcher = 'apachesolr@solr' // your apachesolr server id
$facetApiAdapter = facetapi_adapter_load($searcher);
```

Then if you need to work on active filters:

```
$activeItems = $facetApiAdapter->getAllActiveItems();
foreach ($activeItems as $item_key => $item) {
  $facet = facetapi_facet_load($item['field alias'], $searcher);
  ...
```

Or you can use other FacetApiAdapter methods.